# Sharing of "youtube.com" with "localhost" popup when sharing screen with JS

Tags: javascript, screensharing

I was recently trying to make a screensharing website using JavaScript: the idea behind this is to watch movies together using my own VPS. The issue is when I share a window I get this "popup" which doesn't go away unfortunately...

Oh by the way it is saying: "Sharing "youtube" to "localhost". The browser I am using is Chrome.

[image: That's it]

Does anyone have a solution for my problem?

Comment: I believe this is just Chrome's way of notifying the user that their tab is being shared with another computer. For privacy reasons, it's most likely not possible to remove this nor would it be a good idea to. I'm sure users would like to know when another computer can see their tabs.

Comment: What OS is that? Also what does the popup say? Could you translate it to English, please?

Comment: That is true. However I would like to know if there is any alternative way.

Comment: Use a different browser :-) In mine I can discard that popup.

Comment: That would be an answer to my issue. I think I'll try doing it with Electron JS. Maybe it will solve my problem.